# CSS not loading when changing from element tag to class/id tag

Tags: html, css, image

So I'm having some issues on a project I'm working on. Everything is working well on the website I'm designing up until I noticed I need to change from an img tag on my CSS to either a class or id tag in order to style them individually. When trying to switch it over, it completely disregards the CSS code I've wrote that works fine under an img tag. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

HTML:

```
<div class="me_photo">
    <img src="../../Portfolio Icons/photo_of_me.jpg" alt="Photo of me">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.me_photo {
    width: auto;
    height: 250px;
    margin-left: 45px;
    border: solid 5px;
    border-color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 45px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Output:

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPzvF.jpg)

[class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09Vpm.jpg)

Comment: did you change the css from class selector (.) to id selector(#)? What was your code before and what did you change it to? Your question isn't very clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are targeting the wrong element. The selector you are using is matching the container `div`, instead of the `img`.

Try this:

```css
.me_photo > img {
  width: auto;
  height: 250px;
  margin-left: 45px;
  border: solid 5px;
  border-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 45px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="me_photo">
  <img src="../../Portfolio Icons/photo_of_me.jpg" alt="Photo of me">
</div>
```

Comment: Yup that worked. Thank you so much! For anyone else curious, I did exactly this. Then made another CSS selector for the div itself. After making sure I didn't have any redundant style code between the div itself and .div img all is working great!

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

change your css code => **.me_photo me{}**

```css
.me_photo img {
    width: auto;
    height: 250px;
    margin-left: 45px;
    border: solid 5px;
    border-color: gray;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 45px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="me_photo">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/fjords.jpg" alt="Photo of me">
</div>
```